# Select Statement Conditional WHERE Clause - How do you add a variable not affected by WHERE clause in same query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this SQL query: I need some sort of conditional WHERE clause if possible to use the WHERE clause on EVERYTHING except this Row Below -> $row['value_count_deaths'].

I do not want this one to be filtered and to show the whole number before being filtered.
Is this possible within the same query? If so ... how?

[IMG: I want to accumulate the death number after their name, must be outside WHERE clause](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLrYL.jpg)

Focus of Code:

```
echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['pe_DataPlayers_lastname'] . " " . $row['value_count_deaths'] . "</td>";
```

All overall coded query statement:

```
    echo "<h3> All Pilot Statistics (Realistic/Hardcore) ... only populate stats after last pilot death for each pilot</h3>";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT a.`pe_LogEvent_pilotname`, 
    COUNT(a.`pe_LogEvent_deaths`) AS value_count_deaths,
    COUNT(a.`pe_LogEvent_kills_planes`) AS value_count_kills_planes,
    COUNT(a.`pe_LogEvent_kills_helicopters`) AS value_count_kills_helicopters,
    COUNT(a.`pe_LogEvent_kills_armor`) AS value_count_kills_armor,
    
    b.`pe_DataPlayers_lastname`, 
    b.`pe_DataPlayers_updated`,
    b.`pe_DataPlayers_id`,
    c.`pe_LastPilotDeath_pilotname`,
    c.`pe_LastPilotDeath_datetime` 
    FROM `pe_LogEvent` AS a 
    INNER JOIN `pe_DataPlayers` AS b 
    ON a.pe_LogEvent_pilotname = b.pe_DataPlayers_lastname 
    LEFT JOIN `pe_LastPilotDeath` AS c 
    ON b.pe_DataPlayers_lastname=c.pe_LastPilotDeath_pilotname 
    WHERE a.`pe_LogEvent_datetime` > c.`pe_LastPilotDeath_datetime`
    GROUP BY b.`pe_DataPlayers_lastname` 
    ORDER BY b.`pe_DataPlayers_updated` DESC")) {
    
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<table class='table_stats'>";
        echo "<tr class='table_header'><th>Pilot</th><th>Last Flight Log</th><th>A2A Kills</th><th>A2G Kills</th><th>Sorties</th><th>Landing%</th><th>Deaths</th><th>Ejections</th><th>Crashes</th><th>PVP Kills</th><th>Team Kills</th><th>Planes</th><th>Helos</th><th>Armor</th><th>Light Vehicles</th><th>UnArmored</th><th>Air Defense</th><th>Artillery</th><th>Infantry</th><th>Ships</th><th>Structures</th></tr>"; // First Code                   
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['pe_DataPlayers_lastname'] . " " . $row['value_count_deaths'] . "</td>";      
                echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" .    
$row['value_count_deaths'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['value_count_ejections'] . "</td>";                           
                echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['value_count_crashes'] . "</td>";     
                //echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['value_sum_pvp'] . "</td>";
 

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        
        $result->close();
    }
```

Comment: I think you could radically simplify the query to illustrate the problem that you have.  And then provide sample data and desired results.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Comment: I tried to cut down on the code massively, however I fear that due to all the missing code you won't be able to understand what i'm trying to do. It's MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical approach would be to use a subquery to create a flag.

Your code looks like MySQL, so this uses MySQL syntax conventions:

```
SELECT SELECT pe_LogEvent_pilotname, pe_LogEvent_friendly_fire_killer,
       COUNT(*) as total,
       SUM(pe_LogEvent_crashes IS NOT NULL AND flag) AS value_count_crashes,
       . . .
FROM (SELECT le.*,
             . . . ,   -- other columns you want
             (le.pe_LogEvent_datetime > lpd.pe_LastPilotDeath_datetime) as flag
      FROM pe_LogEvent le JOIN
           pe_DataPlayers dp
           ON le.pe_LogEvent_pilotname = dp.pe_DataPlayers_lastname LEFT JOIN
           pe_LastPilotDeath lpd
          ON dp.pe_DataPlayers_lastname = lpd.pe_LastPilotDeath_pilotname 
     ) x
GROUP BY . . .
```

Comment: Hmmm so basically instead of using a WHERE clause you use this nested flag subquery.
It'll take me some time to try to figure this out, but i'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: I tried all this, it doesn't work.
Next i think this will work:
-INNER JOIN another column from Another Table already used WHERE and adds pilotname + # of deaths (by roman numeral)
- ON pilotnames, this way name will be static to the ancestry with no issues

Comment: Note: by working with UNION and UNION ALL, I learned a ton about what that does and how it works. Very interesting.

Comment: Okay this is now closed, I was able to do an INNER JOIN and create another table that had no time element in it so it just joins a static set of variables to the pilot names.